Prevent .NET BackgroundService running as Windows Service from being stopped
UPDATE: After creating this question and receiving some feedback, I then asked How does Topshelf prevent Windows Service from stopping which was more specific about what I was trying to do and I wanted to attract Topshelf experts.  I didn't update this question because I didn't think it made sense to completely change this question's content since there were already views and responses nor add all the additional content to this question making it overwhelming/unfocused.  Just noting that I did come up with a solution that was serving me well at the time of righting.
Original Question
Following the Create Windows Service using BackgroundService tutorial from Microsoft, I created a new BackgroundService in an attempt to migrate from .Net Framework/Topshelf.
Topshelf had a bool Stop() method that was called before stopping where a return of false prevented the service from shutting down.  I need this functionality and was hoping to accomlish the same with BackgroundService with no success.
My service has some long running processes that run via files being dropped in monitored folders and could run for a very long time (1hr+).  So, if a user (probably me) needs to update the Windows Service code they go and stop the service, update the files, and start the service.  Since there is no progress displayed in Services MMC snap-in, I simply prevent the shutdown if something is running.  My logic allows for a forced shutdown via X shutdown requests within a Y second sliding window, then I will allow the service to shutdown.
I've seen posts that demonstrate using IHostApplicationLifetime and registering a delegate on the CancellationToken ApplicationStopping but I don't want to 'pause' indefinitely, and wait for a job that could run for >1hr or could have a serious problem, so I wanted to 'reject' the request and using my sliding window logic.
The BackgroundService.StopAsync doesn't really offer much help as there is no return or status I can set to prevent the shutdown, the IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication has already been called by the time this overload is executed.
I tried subclassing WindowsServiceLifetime and pass in a ICancelableBackgroundService (my interface), but again the OnStop is too late in the workflow and not able to stop the service shutdown.  The way the ServiceBase was written doesn't really seem to allow 'rejecting' a request.
[System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform( "windows" )]
public class CancelableWindowsServiceLifetime : WindowsServiceLifetime
{
    private readonly ICancelableBackgroundService cancelableBackgroundService;

    public CancelableWindowsServiceLifetime( IHostEnvironment environment, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ICancelableBackgroundService cancelableBackgroundService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<HostOptions> optionsAccessor )
        : this( environment, applicationLifetime, cancelableBackgroundService, loggerFactory, optionsAccessor, Options.Create( new WindowsServiceLifetimeOptions() ) )
    {
    }

    public CancelableWindowsServiceLifetime( IHostEnvironment environment, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ICancelableBackgroundService cancelableBackgroundService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<HostOptions> optionsAccessor, IOptions<WindowsServiceLifetimeOptions> windowsServiceOptionsAccessor )
        : base( environment, applicationLifetime, loggerFactory, optionsAccessor, windowsServiceOptionsAccessor )
    {
        this.cancelableBackgroundService = cancelableBackgroundService;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if ( !cancelableBackgroundService.CanStop() )
        {
            // What should we do here?  Neither exceptions or return stop host service from shutting down.
            // throw new InvalidOperationException( "CancelableBackgroundService is currently processing, cannot stop service." ); // This still does not prevent service from shutting down
            // return; // This still does not prevent service from shutting down.
        }

        base.OnStop();
    }
}

Are there any patterns/mechanisms to achieve the behavior I've described?

OnStop is called by Windows' SCM, so if you throw inside there then SCM will see that your program is apparently in some kind of death throes so of course it's going to euphanize your program. The solution here is not to override OnStop but instead to set your service's SCM configuration to mark the service as un-stoppable-by-policy so OnStop won't be called in the first place.

Updated question, I just left my 'last' attempt of throw in my code.  I don't want to prevent stopping in case I do want/need to forcibly stop the service.  I created another post explaining what I've looked at for code, but assuming I did want to mark as un-stoppable, what is the pattern for that?  You can answer on that post if you want, but simply setting CanStop doesn't really do anything in Service base until another call to SetServiceStatus is called.

A sample code that works in .NET 6 or later (no conflict even if you have added the "Topshelf" nugget package to the project).
It was tested using "Service Control Manager (SCM)"
If "IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping" is set, on "Graceful Shutdown" of service, Windows will wait for the operation defined in that event to complete.
If the operation is long, for example, it takes 5 minutes, Windows will display an error message and, of course, in this code that we wrote, it will stop the service after the operation.

To test the code, do the following steps:

1- Create a "Worker Service" type solution in "Visual Studio 2022".
2- Add the nugget package
"Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" with appropriate
version to the .NET project. For example, if you use .NET 6, version 6 works.
3- Replace the "Worker.cs" and "Program.cs" files with the following
codes and build the project in "Debug" or "Release" mode.
4- Run "cmd.exe" as administrator and then install service using  command same as follows:
sc Create TestService BinPath= "D:\Projects\TestService\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestService.exe"

5- Start and then stop the service using SCM. Notice "C:\[Temp]\test.txt". After clicking the "Stop" menu in "SCM", about 40 seconds later, the service will stop, and during this time, if you delete "test.txt", the service will recreate it.

Worker.cs:
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _HostApplicationLifetime;
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IHostApplicationLifetime HostApplicationLifetime)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _HostApplicationLifetime = HostApplicationLifetime;
            _HostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
             {
                 while (!IsTerminatedJob && (ElapsedSecondsAfterStartingService < MaxDelayTimeForServiceTerminationInSeconds))
                     Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
             });
        }
        public static bool IsTerminatedJob { get; set; } = false;
        public int ElapsedSecondsAfterStartingService = 0;
        public int MaxDelayTimeForServiceTerminationInSeconds = 0;
        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IsTerminatedJob = false;
            ElapsedSecondsAfterStartingService = 0;
            MaxDelayTimeForServiceTerminationInSeconds = 40;
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // To specify that the service can be terminated, set "IsTerminatedJob = true"
                ElapsedSecondsAfterStartingService++;
                WriteTestFile();
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        public void WriteTestFile()
        {
            CreateTextFile("test.txt", "service is running");
        }
        public void CreateTextFile(string FileName, string Message)
        {
            const string FILE_PATH = @"C:\[Temp]";
            if (!Directory.Exists(FILE_PATH))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(FILE_PATH);
            File.WriteAllText(FILE_PATH + @"\" + FileName, Message);
            Console.Beep();
        }

    }

Program.cs:
using TestService;

var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddHostedService<Worker>())
    .UseWindowsService(options => options.ServiceName = "TestService")
    .Build();

builder.Run();


Other solution:
There is another solution that is not so easy and interesting! If possible, replace the "StopAsync" method of the "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host" class with your own designed method at runtime. This may be done by "reflection" or any other allowed approach. To prevent the service from stopping, I think that in addition to the "StopAsync" method in the "BackgroundService" class, the "StopAsync" method in the "Host" class should also be overridden, which doesn't handle these things the way you want.

I saw this feature but it doesn't satisfy what I want.  I want an immediate response saying unable to stop, and then permit more stop requests.  I think above just blocks for a 'while' (i.e. 5 mins) and then the windows service stops.  I believe in my Topshelf implementation, if I permitted the shutdown while a background job was running, the 'service' (windows service) stopped, and the 'background job' was also terminated.  I think you are saying in yours that after 5 minute 'wait' attempt from SCM, the service stopped, but the background job continued running?

To add to my comment, there were times (maybe all ironed out) where one of my background jobs threw an exception and didn't signal to Hangfire that it was done/failed, so process continued to run (rather wait), so I had to forcibly shutdown the service to update the code (fix bug).  In implementation above, I think it would be stuck forever in a 'processing' state and dll would be in use.

No @Terry, I meant the exact opposite. I posted that photo to say that if it takes 5 minutes or more, it is true that it shows an error, but the process continues until the end of the job and after the job is finished, the service stops. I designed the code using parameters. You can set "MaxDelayTimeForServiceTerminationInSeconds" to 3600 seconds and wait an hour to see how the code works. After the job is done, the service will not get stuck in processing unless you set the service's TimeOut setting to a large number.

If your code gives an error, no problem. Inside "ExecuteAsync" whenever all your routines are successful, set "IsTerminatedJob" to true and it will allow Windows to stop the service. Also according to the documentation, this event is executed in "Graceful Shutdown" mode. If you restart Windows, I think the service will be stopped immediately, although I have not tried.
Fortunately, the process "ExecuteAsync" and "ApplicationStopping" are not related and both are executed together. So there is no problem and when the job is finished, you can stop the service by setting IsTerminatedJob.

In any case, I think the correct answer to your question, "Prevent .NET BackgroundService running as Windows Service from being stopped", is "ApplicationStopping". However, you cannot expect anything beyond Windows standards. On the other hand, imagine that you are a user and want to stop a service, and immediately Windows gives a message that it is not possible! what do you think? Wouldn't you think Windows has a bug that doesn't try to stop the service?

You want Windows to quickly say that "stopping the service is not possible". For this, first, you must see if Windows services have this capability, and second, you must hack the basic classes of the host service and change the codes according to your opinion. In that case, it is not known whether it will work correctly again in the next Microsoft updates.

Apparently, others didn't offer exactly what you wanted. I think that if a more precise answer is not received by the next few days, you should solve your problem with this method.

Regarding the "Force Shutdown" of the Windows service, if there are several types of Stop service, there should be a way to process Stop types within the service. If the stop type was mandatory, immediately set "IsTerminatedJob" to true to stop the service as normal.

"imagine that you are a user and want to stop a service" - I am the user :)  And I want to prevent myself from trashing running processes if I attempt to stop the service to perform a maintenance update of the code.  If I see 'can't stop', then I know a job is running and just to wait a bit.  If I know I want it to stop immediately, I just issue 3 stop commands within 1 minute and then the service is permitted to stop.  That's the whole point of this.  Thanks for all the digging into this.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

OK, thanks. I wrote my opinion about your comment in the chat room.

I know this may be a long shot, but sometime we get so lost in the problem that we miss the solution.
Can't you achieve this with libraries like :
Quartz
or
Hangfire

We also use Hangfire for some services but if/when I migrate them off Topshelf I assume I'll have same problem.  If someone can stop their service immediately, I'm pretty sure we had problems in our jobs that were running b/c they couldn't support stop and restart, so they failed.  I'd have to dig deeper to remember exactly what happened when a Hangfire job was running and the host was stopped.  But for the service I'm trying to convert now, I think Hangfire is overkill. (I've never looked at Quartz).
