How does Topshelf prevent Windows Service from stopping
Trying to replicate the behavior of preventing Stop command in a .NET 7 Windows Service.  As I read Topshelf code, their service host is subclassing ServiceBase and in the OnStop override, if the _serviceHandle.Stop(this) returns false, it throws exception.  This sets ExitCode = 1064 and rethrows.
    public class WindowsServiceHost :
        ServiceBase,
        Host,
        HostControl
    {

        // omitted for brevity

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                _log.Info("[Topshelf] Stopping");

                if (!_serviceHandle.Stop(this))
                    throw new TopshelfException("The service did not stop successfully (return false).");

                _log.Info("[Topshelf] Stopped");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _settings.ExceptionCallback?.Invoke(ex);

                _log.Fatal("The service did not shut down gracefully", ex);
                ExitCode = (int) TopshelfExitCode.ServiceControlRequestFailed;
                throw;
            }
        }

Then, looking at the ServiceBase code, it simply calls OnStop and if exception is throw, just re-set the service status to 'previous' (running) and rethrow.
        private unsafe void DeferredStop () 
        {
            fixed (NativeMethods.SERVICE_STATUS *pStatus = &status) 
            {
                int previousState = status.currentState;

                status.checkPoint = 0;
                status.waitHint = 0;
                status.currentState = NativeMethods.STATE_STOP_PENDING;
                NativeMethods.SetServiceStatus (statusHandle, pStatus);
                try 
                {
                    OnStop();

                    // omitted for brevity...
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    status.currentState = previousState;
                    NativeMethods.SetServiceStatus (statusHandle, pStatus);
                    WriteEventLogEntry (Res.GetString (Res.StopFailed, e.ToString ()), EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    throw; 
                }
            } // fixed
        } // DeferredStop

I've created my own class for .NET 7 deriving from WindowsServiceLifetime (which itself derives from ServiceBase) with the following 'same' code, but after I throw exception in OnStop the service does stop.
[System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform( "windows" )]
public class CancelableWindowsServiceLifetime : Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices.WindowsServiceLifetime
{
    private readonly ICancelableBackgroundService cancelableBackgroundService;

    public CancelableWindowsServiceLifetime( IHostEnvironment environment, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ICancelableBackgroundService cancelableBackgroundService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<HostOptions> optionsAccessor )
        : this( environment, applicationLifetime, cancelableBackgroundService, loggerFactory, optionsAccessor, Options.Create( new WindowsServiceLifetimeOptions() ) )
    {
    }

    public CancelableWindowsServiceLifetime( IHostEnvironment environment, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ICancelableBackgroundService cancelableBackgroundService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<HostOptions> optionsAccessor, IOptions<WindowsServiceLifetimeOptions> windowsServiceOptionsAccessor )
        : base( environment, applicationLifetime, loggerFactory, optionsAccessor, windowsServiceOptionsAccessor )
    {
        this.cancelableBackgroundService = cancelableBackgroundService;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if ( !cancelableBackgroundService.CanStop() )
        {
            ExitCode = 1064; // ERROR_EXCEPTION_IN_SERVICE

            throw new ApplicationException( $"Unable to stop service at this time." );
        }

        base.OnStop();
    }
}

I looked at the .NET 7 version of ServiceBase and don't see any real differences in the implementation.  Any ideas why my version is not working?
Essentially, I want to prevent stopping my service in case jobs are running, however, I do have a safe guard in place that if stop is requested enough times in a sliding window, it'll permit the stop to happen and terminate the running job.

You can configure the stop time in HostOptions.ShutdownTimeout, but you should stop your service as soon as Windows asks you to.

Well, I'll keep digging.  I take 'Windows asks you to' as a 'shutdown' command.  Which I permit.  But when a user requests a 'stop' from SCM, I don't want to stop/kill a long running process if there is one in process (unless the user 'forces' it by a couple requests within a sliding window - this worked great in Topshelf, but all our libraries are migrating to .NET 7, thus my attempt at a conversion).  I'll post answer if I ever solve it.

Just a reminder that .NET 7 has been out of support since May 14th and there won't be any developments there.

In case anyone wants to know the solution I'm currently using, this is how I achieved my goal:

By default, prevent the user (normally me) from stopping the service if there are jobs running, but allow for a forced shutdown if needed (event if there are jobs running).

The basic idea was to follow the pattern of .NET Core websites and AppOffline.htm file presence.  When a 'Stop' request comes in, delay the stopping of the service indefinitely while there were jobs running or the existence of a SvcOffline.txt file.  That way, if a user requests a stop, it'll be 'prevented', however, if they need to force the shutdown regardless of running jobs, they can simply drop a SvcOffline.txt file in the service directory to permit the shutdown.
The experience in SCM was as follows:

Start service. (envision that jobs start processing and are long running).
Attempt to stop the service.  SCM will display the message:


Windows is attempting to stop the following service on Local Computer...KAT FTP Service


If the jobs finish (or SvcOffline.txt exists) before the 'failed to stop' message is displayed, everything shuts down gracefully.

If the service does not stop before the following message, SCM displays a status of 'Stopping' and once the service does shutdown, SCM removes the status flag.



Windows could not stop the KAT FTP Service service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Note: If the service does not allow the shutdown before the 'failed to stop' message, SCM throws an AggregateException that must be caught.
Below is the code I used to accomplish this.  Any comments are welcome.
Program.cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
    .ConfigureServices( ( builder, services ) =>
    {
        services
            .AddWindowsService( options => options.ServiceName = "KAT FTP Service" )
            .AddHostedService<Worker>();
    } )
    .Build();

try
{
    host.Run(); 
}
catch ( Exception ex ) when ( ex is AggregateException aggEx && aggEx.InnerException is OperationCanceledException )
{
    // Ignore this error.  If the Service was attempted to be stopped and blocked the stop long enough for SCM to
    // display an 'Unable to stop' message, this exception will be thrown, but if the InnerException is OperationCanceledException,
    // meaning that the service either finished or permitted the stop via SvcShutdown.txt, just ignore.
}

Worker.cs
public partial class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment;
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> logger;
    private readonly List<FileWatcherNotification> monitors = new();
    private ServiceSettings settings;

    public Worker( IOptionsMonitor<ServiceSettings> settingsMonitor, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment, ILogger<Worker> logger )
    {
        this.hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        this.logger = logger;
        settings = settingsMonitor.CurrentValue;

        // Delay service stop indefinitely until jobs are finished or forced shutdown
        hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register( () =>
        {
            StopMonitors(); // prevent new notifications from being processed

            while ( !CanStop )
            {
                Task.Delay( 10 * 1000 ).Wait();
            }

            DisposeMonitors();
        } );
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync( CancellationToken stoppingToken )
    {
        try
        {
            await InitializeMonitorsAsync( settings );

            // This service simply reacts to FileWatcherNotifications so nothing
            // to do here except wait for the service to stop.

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
            using var registration = stoppingToken.Register( s => ( (TaskCompletionSource)s! ).SetResult(), tcs );
            await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait( false );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ) when ( ex is not OperationCanceledException)
        {
            logger.LogError( ex, "{message}", ex.Message );
            Environment.Exit( 1 );
        }
    }

    private bool shutdownBlockWarned;
    public bool CanStop
    {
        get
        {
            var workerCount = monitors.Sum( m => m.CurrentWorkers );

            if ( workerCount == 0 ) return true;

            if ( !shutdownBlockWarned )
            {
                LogWarningBlockingShutdown( workerCount );
                shutdownBlockWarned = true;
            }

            var svcOfflinePath = Path.Combine( hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "SvcOffline.txt" );
            if ( File.Exists( svcOfflinePath ) )
            {
                var filesProcessing = monitors.SelectMany( m => m.ProcessingFiles ).Join( Environment.NewLine );
                LogErrorForcedShutdown( workerCount, filesProcessing );

                File.Move( svcOfflinePath, Path.Combine( hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "_SvcOffline.txt" ) );

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}


It's a good idea. Of course, there are no complete details of the code and it cannot be tested for me, but if this code is executable (as you tested), the idea used is good (offline file).
Especially since you mentioned that if trying to stop the service faces problem (by SCM before the timeout),  an exception inside the servics is raised that can be catched.
Great that you found a solution to the problem. Of course, the idea may be possible to improve in the future.

I'll get straight to the point:

Essentially, I want to prevent stopping my service in case jobs are running

You can't do that.
Y'see, Windows absolutely requires a Service's Control Handler Function to correctly handle all applicable requests. Specifically, if a service says it is stoppable, then it must handle an incoming SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP request in one of 2 ways:

Stop very quickly by immediately updating its status to SERVICE_STOPPED (but be careful with your threads).
Respond immediately by updating its status to SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, whereupon your service must transition to SERVICE_STOPPED within the WaitToKillServiceTimeout time limit.

While in the SERVICE_STOP_PENDING state, your service can meekly
request more time to complete stopping via SERVICE_STATUS.waitHint, but don't press your luck: if you take longer than WaitToKillServiceTimeout then Windows will kill your service process.




Otherwise, Windows will simply forcibly kill the process hosting your service, with extreme prejudice.

(this is an addendum) However, when a Windows Service is running on the .NET Framework (v2.0 through v4.8+) then unhandled exceptions thrown from within OnStop() are silently swallowed despite the SCM's requirements; in your case, this is the Topshelf exception in your post: throw new TopshelfException("The service did not stop successfully (return false).");


...but what you can do is:

Option 1: Configure your service so that it cannot be stopped (NOT_STOPPABLE).

This is why some Running services in Services.msc  have a disabled Stop button.
This is done by not returning the SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP flag in response to SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE requests.
...which means your service will never normally receive a SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP requests.
Note this still requires you to correctly handle SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN - and any other SERVICE_CONTROL_... messages your service claism to handle.


Option 2: Handle SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP and indicate SERVICE_STOP_PENDING and maybe request more time if needed, but don't count on it.



I'm trying to replicate the behavior of preventing Stop command in a .NET 7 Windows Service

That's not what the Topshelf code actually does...

and in the OnStop override, if the _serviceHandle.Stop(this) returns false, it throws exception. This sets ExitCode = 1064 and rethrows.

The re-throw is a red-herring because the process is doomed at this point - the final throw is just the final kiss-of-death. Y'see, this is how the flow-of-execution goes:

The user - or Windows SCM - decides to stop your service - and so calls Win32's ControlService( scHandle, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ... ) function.

Windows SCM gets the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP message and uses the dispatcher thread (that it created earlier) to call ServiceBase.ServiceCommandCallbackEx(command: SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)...

which passes into ServiceBase.ServiceCommandCallback(command)
which handles SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP by immediately indicating SERVICE_STOP_PENDING for you already (you have no choice in the matter, as you cannot override this method).
which then uses the .NET Thread Pool to run ServiceBase.DeferredStop asynchronously, thus allowing the thread inside ServiceCommandCallback to return back to the SCM, while the thread-pool thread runs the ServiceBase.DeferredStop method.

For .NET 5+: If you're on .NET 5+ (and probably versions of .NET Core too), ServiceBase uses ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to run DeferredStop which means any unhandled exceptions inside DeferredStop will result in the entire process being killed (this is described in Step 3 below).
For .NET Framework 2.0 through 4.8: the ServiceBase class uses new DeferredHandlerDelegate(this.DeferredStop).BeginInvoke(callback: null, object: null) to run DeferredStop on the thread-pool and without calling EndInvoke either - which means that any unhandled exception thrown within DeferredStop will be silently swallowed .

This is a horrifically bad design on Microsoft's part.
Windows SCM seems to be aware of this particular situation because during my experiments SCM indicated ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL from ControlService( ..., SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE ) despite it ostensibly being in the RUNNING state. BTW, this specific check is how WMI is able to mark the service as "Degraded" when you run wmi service $svcName (though other tools, like `sc status $svcName`` don't indicate any problems, which is annoyingly inconsistent).


For .NET Framework 1.1: ServiceBase runs OnStop synchronously within its SCM callback method; while it does log all exceptions in OnStop it still silently swallows them too. Ew.




(Anyway, assuming we're on .NET 5 or later) So the thread-pool thread is now inside ServiceBase.DeferredStop....

...which then calls the virtual method ServiceBase.OnStop synchronously.

...if OnStop() throws any exception then that will be caught by DeferredStop and logged to the Windows Event Log, and then re-thrown.

Before you ask where that re-thrown exception ends-up, remember this is in a .NET Thread Pool thread - which means only one thing can happen:

The common language runtime or a host process terminates the thread

...followed by:

termination of the application.


ouch!






Then, looking at the ServiceBase code, it simply calls OnStop and if exception is thrown, just re-set the service status to 'previous' (running) and rethrow.

I'll admit that I do not know exactly why DeferredStop calls SetServiceStatus with the previousState (which would mostly be SERVICE_RUNNING) because such a transition (from …_STOP_PENDING to …_RUNNING) is invalid - however it is documented that SCM will accept "invalid" transitions.
I will say that this is unusual: no other publicly available sample/example code from Microsoft that demonstrates handling a STOP request will try to re-set a service's status back after already setting it to STATE_STOP_PENDING.
But consider that in .NET Framework 2.0 through 4.8, the throw right-after the WriteEventLogEntry( StopFailed... ) call gets swallowed - now I speculate that SCM's behaviour of blocking any further service-commands while it's in the STOP_PENDING state is the reason why ServiceBase will re-set the service's status to RUNNING  (and I note this does seems to "work" insofar as Services.msc says it's no-longer Stopping) - because when it's RUNNING again it should be able to attempt Stopping again...
...though in my
and then letting the CLR terminate it provides a stronger hint to the SCM that something bad happened, whereas if a service is in the STOP_PENDING state and then terminates while skipping the _STOPPED state), is less-likely to be seen as an unusual failure by system-monitoring software. (Honestly, I don't know).
...but none of this does anything that could be described as "preventing" or evading a SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP command.

UPDATE: I dug-up System.ServiceProcess.dll from .NET Framework 1.1 and saw its ServiceBase class for comparison. Interestingly, it does not run OnStop in the thread-pool (but runs it synchronously) - and its try/catch block (for OnStop) logs the exception too, but does not re-throw it, and also re-sets currentState to either RUNNING or PAUSED.
...but that's in-line with the documentation for the contemporaneous Windows XP (emphasis mine):

If a service accepts the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP control code, it must stop upon receipt, going to either the SERVICE_STOP_PENDING or SERVICE_STOPPED state. After the SCM sends this control code, it will not send other control codes.
Windows XP: If the service returns NO_ERROR and continues to run, it continues to receive control codes. This behavior changed starting with Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2).

I dug through various "what's changed in XP SP2?" documentation but couldn't find any description of what behavior exactly changed - but I speculate that prior to SP2 the SCM would allow invalid state transitions but post-SP2 it does not, because otherwise a misbehaving service could flip from STOPPING to RUNNING and use that to perpetually stall whatever operation required the service to stop.

Incredibly deep explanation.  Appreciated. Serious Q: 'That's not what the Topshelf code actually does.' do you have experience with Topshelf?  I might not have made it clear, but I was a 'user' of Topshelf and used this feature (returning false from Stop( HostControl hostControl ) if I had a running job I didn't want to kill.  Note, there is no way I see with Topshelf to tell it NOT to accept stop commands.  Maybe I was abusing the feature, but that abuse has saved me many times :)  I guess I just can't decipher their code well enough to figure out how they gracefully prevented stops.

@Terry I'll admit it's possible that Topshelf might be fiddling with something else (i.e. non-obvious side-effects). I'd appreciate it if you could link me to an example Topshelf project with minimal-code that has this behavior and I'll investigate what's going on.

I'll make a repo tomorrow hopefully for you to peek at.

@Terry thank you, I  appreciate it.  I’m doing this because I’m working on a Windows Service myself right now, and so I want (and need) to be certain I understand what’s going on under-the-hood.

You can find a sample repository that prevents shutdown of the service until it has been requested three times.  You can try it in Console via CTRL-C or SCM.

Well...I have to eat my words.  Our services have been pretty stable and I haven't needed to stop/update them forever.  I know before I could stop, get the warning and either make multiple requests to force the shutdown or wait a minute or two and check again.  However, I just tested the repo I made you as a SCM and it behaved as I've mentioned in my questions.  It does indeed stop the shutdown, but I get the same behavior where after the first stop rejection, all others state that service is unable to accept commands.  This definitely wasn't the way it behaved in the past (several years ago).

@Terry How do I install this KATShutdown service in the linked project repo?

If you build it, from elevated command prompt just run the .exe install (install flag).  That should install it.  Probably have to use sc.exe to uninstall/delete.

@Terry I found out the reason, and arguably it's a bug in the design of ServiceBase, and it means my answer has a big mistake in it; in short,  the .NET Framework version of ServiceBase (but not the .NET Core / .NET 5+ version) uses Delegate.BeginInvoke with null arguments, it means the thrown TopshelfException will be swallowed by the CLR leaving no trace (not even a memory-leak). This is an incredibly bad design.

@Terry I've updated my answer. So now we know why your previous code seemed to have "worked" in .NET Framework 4.x, but the truth is that Windows SCM definitely knows the service is in a broken/botched state despite the swallowed exception. Fortunately .NET 5+ won't swallow and will have the CLR kill the process so the service won't be left in an indeterminate state.

FYI, looks like you didn't save update, it just says 'Update 2'

@Terry my mistake - I started writing it there but then I moved it into the main part of my post. I’ll remove the vestigial part now. You can see my actual changes via the View History link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78879305/revisions

What you want is to have more time for your service to start.
For that, you need to call ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime to request additional time.
WindowsServiceLifetime does derive from ServiceBase, but there's no in-the box functionality to invoke that.
This is done via SetServiceStatus function (winsvc.h).
You need to find the best way to do it for your particular case.

Did you mean 'more time for your service to stop'?  If I request 5 more seconds, what happens after 5 seconds?  Forcibly shutdown?  Or another stop command is issued?  Also curious, was my assumption on the code that was running from within Topshelf above correct?  If so, I assume that the pattern used doesn't work for BackgroundService?

Sorry! I think I totally misunderstood your question. I read it as requesting more time to start the service.

Of course, this solution may not be the answer to the question that asks how to do with "TopShelf" in .NET 7.
But it is not bad to check it.
If we can create a service using "ServiceBase" instead of "BackgroundService" for .NET 7, we can write code that during operation, if the "Stop" menu in "SCM (Service Control Manager)" is used, Windows immediately displays the message "Windows could not stop the service" and the operation continues, but if the "Stop" menu is used after the operation is finished, the service will be stopped quickly without an error message.
Similar to the images below:


For doing this, we create an unstoppable service like the code below and then depend that service on our main service. So its execution requires the execution of main service. At the end of the operation, we can kill the process of "unstoppable service" and then the main service can be stopped.
Note: A .NET Core service apparently cannot depend on a .NET 4.6 service, and both must be the same. If we use "sc config" to associate two incompatible services by mistake, the command will be executed, but the service will not be usable.
Of course, the following code works well for the .NET 4.6 project, but it may need changes to be used in NET Core 6 and later.
Note: The name of the Visual Studio project is important here. The name of the executable module for "unstoppable service" is used in the "main service" code, so if the project name is different, it should also be applied in the service code.
TestServiceNotStoppable.cs:
namespace TestServiceNotStoppable
{
    public partial class TestServiceNotStoppable : ServiceBase
    {
        public TestServiceNotStoppable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CanStop = false;
            CanShutdown = false;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }
}

Program.cs (A sample file for NET 4.6 - project type "Windows Service (.NET Framework)":
namespace TestServiceNotStoppable
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new TestServiceNotStoppable()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}

TestServiceOld.cs (Main service):
public partial class TestServiceOld : ServiceBase
{
    public TestServiceOld()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public const string SERVICE_NAME_NOT_STOPPABLE = "TestServiceNotStoppable";
    public const string TEST_FILE_PATH = @"C:\[Temp]";

    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private readonly Stopwatch _Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private void MakeCurrentService_Stoppable()
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(SERVICE_NAME_NOT_STOPPABLE).FirstOrDefault();
        process?.Kill();
    }
    private void MakeCurrentService_NotStoppable()
    {
        var controller = new ServiceController(SERVICE_NAME_NOT_STOPPABLE);
        controller.Start();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
        _Stopwatch.Start();
    }
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        MakeCurrentService_NotStoppable();
        ExecuteTask();
        MakeCurrentService_Stoppable();
    }
    private void ExecuteTask()
    {
        while (ElapsedSeconds < 25)
        {
            WriteTestFile();
            Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    public int ElapsedSeconds
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)_Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        base.OnStop();
    }
    public void WriteTestFile()
    {
        CreateTextFile("Test.txt", "service is running");
    }
    public void CreateTextFile(string FileName, string Message)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(TEST_FILE_PATH))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(TEST_FILE_PATH);
        var FilePath = Path.Combine(TEST_FILE_PATH, FileName);
        File.WriteAllText(FilePath, Message);
        Console.Beep();
    }
}

With the following command in "cmd.exe" with administrator access, we create the two services:
sc Create TestServiceNotStoppable BinPath= "D:Projects\TestServiceNotStoppable\TestServiceNotStoppable\bin\Debug\TestServiceNotStoppable.exe"
sc Create TestServiceOld BinPath= "D:Projects\TestServiceOld\TestServiceOld\bin\Debug\TestServiceOld.exe"

With the following command in "cmd.exe" with administrator access, we connect the two services together:
sc config TestServiceNotStoppable depend=TestServiceOld

Now, if you start the "TestServiceOld" service in SCM, "TestServiceNotStoppable" will also start and if you stop "TestServiceOld" before 25 seconds, Windows will give a quick error message and the operation will continue, and if "Stop" is used after 25 seconds, the service will stop without any problem.
Notice the file "C:\[Temp]\Test.txt". When the main service is running ("TestServiceOld"), if we delete "Test.txt", the service will recreate it.

""Stop" is used after 25 seconds, the service will stop without any problem." - When this happens, do you see any Error events logged to any of the Event Logs?

@Dai, you asked if an error is logged when the service is stopped after 25 seconds (after the test operation is completed), I haven't tried but I think it shouldn't be logged because no error occurs. Actually our main service is a normal stoppable service. We only run the dependent service in the "Start" of the main service and before starting the operation, and "SCM" considering that the stop of our service may cause the stop of the dependent services, asks questions and that service cannot be stopped and finally, the stoppage of the main service will be canceled during the critical operation

I know I asked a similar question that you worked on Babak, but this seems like it does what I mentioned before, this is blocking shutdown while process is running no matter what.  I want to have a way to stop the shutdown the majority of the time (i.e. if I try to stop and didn't know a job was running), but there ARE times when I do want to allow a stop even if a job is running.  Effectively what I am coding is a 'are you sure you want to shut down the service, a job is running' prompt.  I'll post what I came up with tomorrow morning, doing final testing on it now.

@Terry, The same method as you said before that if you leave an "offline file" the service will be stopped is good and it works for this situation as well.
But I have checked "TopShelf' more closely and published it as another answer a few minutes ago.

@Terry, As you know in your other question, I told a way to prevent the service from stopping in .NET Core (using BackgroundService), that is done with error number 1053 and it would take a while
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78840625/prevent-net-backgroundservice-running-as-windows-service-from-being-stopped/78869235#78869235
but in this question, I told a method to prevent the service from stopping for .NET 4.6 (using ServiceBase),  with error 1052, and without delay in displaying error message to the user.

In any case, it is possible to prevent the service from stopping with two completely different methods.

Of course, a few days ago I said in the chat room (the comments) of your other question:
"I've tried many things about the possibility of creating a quick "service not stopped" message in .NET Core, but they didn't work. I made a post about your second question (TopShelf). Please take a look at it , it might be useful."

@Terry, I deleted my second answer about using "TopShelf" a few minutes ago. Considering that the mentioned answer did not help to solve your problem and of course my knowledge about "TopShelf" is not enough and I may have made a mistake in that answer and mislead others. Especially since this question was "bounty" and it has been in the attention of experts for several days, I need to write an answer that I am sure of its correctness.

@Terry, according to the comment you made on Dai's post "This definitely wasn't the way it behaved in the past (several years ago)" and according to the test I did with your Repository, I am more sure that my second answer is probably true and I undeleted it. I hope it was useful in any case for you and others.

Is the 'second' answer the one here above?  WIth two services?  That would probably work, I guess I just didn't want that amount of complexity for the few times I'd need to prevent the shutdown.  Again, thanks again for all the digging.

No @Terry, I mean this answer I wrote after the answer above about trying to stop the service using "TopShelf" in Windows 11 and .NET Core 7. Then I felt it might be wrong and deleted it and restored it hours later after your comment under Dai's post. I thought to myself, maybe the second answer will be useful for those who have the same problem. In any case, I thank you too.

Topshelf doesn't inherently prevent Windows services from stopping. It provides a framework for building Windows services in .NET, but the actual stopping behavior is largely determined by your service's implementation and configuration.
Here are some key factors that influence a service's stopping behavior:
Service Implementation:
Graceful Shutdown: Proper implementation of the Stop method in your service class is crucial. This method should perform necessary cleanup tasks, such as closing connections, saving data, and stopping background threads.
Dependency Management: Ensure that all external dependencies (e.g., databases, message queues) are handled correctly during the shutdown process.
Timeout Handling: Implement timeouts for long-running operations to prevent the service from hanging during shutdown.
Topshelf Configuration:
Service Control Manager Interaction: Topshelf manages the interaction with the Service Control Manager (SCM). It provides mechanisms for notifying the SCM about service status changes.
Custom Handlers: While not a common practice, you can potentially implement custom handlers to intercept stop requests and modify the behavior if needed. However, this should be done with caution as it can introduce complexity and potential issues.
Common Issues and Solutions:
Infinite Loops or Blocking Operations: These can prevent the service from stopping gracefully. Use proper synchronization and timeout mechanisms to avoid these situations.
Resource Leaks: Unmanaged resources can hinder the shutdown process. Ensure proper resource disposal.
External Dependencies: Handle external dependencies carefully to avoid blocking the shutdown.
Topshelf Configuration Errors: Incorrect Topshelf configuration can lead to unexpected behavior. Review your configuration settings.

This looks like it was written by ChatGPT (and badly formatted to boot...)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have checked "TopShelf' more closely. Probably in Windows 11, it is not possible to prevent the service from stopping with the mechanism considered in the "TopShelf" framework.
So I think the answer to the question "How does Topshelf prevent Windows Service from stopping" is:
The programmer can tell "TopShelf" not to stop the service simply by returning "false" in the "Stop" method, and then the framework will throw an exception during the stop operation to prevent the service from stopping, but possibly "TopShelf" will not work properly in Windows 11 in this case and Microsoft's new policies prevent it. Of course, it needs a more detailed investigation.
I think that in Windows 11, if there is a problem in the service stop operation, the service process will be killed by "SCM (Service Control Manager)", whether the operation of stopping the service encounters an error or whether the error does not occur but stopping the service takes longer than the specified timeout.
Of course, there are allowed methods to continue the service before stopping, for example the "IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping" event, which is described here. It can also be done by using service dependencies, which is described in my other answer to this question (here):
Documentation related to the use of "TopShelf" (Sep 24, 2018) can be found here, that is a bit outdated and doesn't say anything specific about how to prevent the service from stopping in "Windows 11". Also online documentation
In order to check whether it is possible to easily prevent the service from stopping in Windows 11 using "TopShelf" in .NET Core, we need to create a simple "TopShelf" service with the following steps:

1- We create a "Console App" project for .NET Core 6 or later in Visual Studio 2022
2- We install the "TopShelf" nuget package in the project.
3- Add the following class and also change Program.cs similar to the
following code:

TestServiceUsingTopshelf.cs:
using Topshelf;

namespace TestServiceUsingTopShelf
{
    public class TestServiceUsingTopshelf
    {
        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            //hostControl.RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
            return true;
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using TestServiceUsingTopShelf;
using Topshelf;

HostFactory.Run(configure =>
{
    configure.Service<TestServiceUsingTopshelf>(service =>
    {
        service.ConstructUsing(s => new TestServiceUsingTopshelf());
        service.WhenStarted((s, hostControl) => s.Start(hostControl));
        service.WhenStopped((s, hostControl) => s.Stop(hostControl));

    });
    //Setup Account that window service use to run.  
    configure.RunAsLocalSystem();
    configure.SetServiceName("TestServiceUsingTopshelf");
    configure.SetDisplayName("TestServiceUsingTopshelf");
    configure.SetDescription("Test Service");
});


4- We build the project. Then we install the service with the
following command in cmd.exe with administrator access.

sc create TestServiceUsingTopShelf binpath=D:\[Projects]\TestServiceUsingTopShelf\TestServiceUsingTopShelf\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestServiceUsingTopShelf.exe

If we "Start" and "Stop" the service, it will work correctly.
Now, if we change the "Stop" method to return false and press Ctrl+C after running it in the console program, the output of the console program will be as follows:

It means that TopShelf realized that we don't want the service to stop, but if we stop the service in SCM, the error dialog will be displayed and the service will be stopped.

It is not useful to work with the host parameter in "Stop". Also if we create an exception inside "Stop" method, we get an error again in SCM and it doesn't work.
Probably, SCM in Windows 11 does not allow TopShelf to work properly and if the process takes a long time and is not stopped, it will kill it.
Maybe if we create the service by inheriting from "TopShelf" classes like "WindowsServiceHost" or other classes, we will get a better answer and get closer to solving the problem. In any case, it needs further investigation.
